# Tracking when / where a variable is set in Javascript using FireBug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am currently using FireBug to see how hypem delivers it the content to allow its flash player to work (specifically the play button functionality).  I have found that the `trackList` variable is populated with the data but I do not know where it is set.

How can I track when / where this collection is modified? I can add a watch to it but don't know how to trap when it is set.

FYI I am doing this as I want some of this functionality and want to understand how they have done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't directly possible.

Instead, you can search through the Javascript and see where the variable is set, then put a normal breakpoint on each line that you find.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately can't seem to find out where it is set!

Comment: Try calling `defineProperty` and putting a breakpoint or `console.log` call in the property.

Comment: Sorry but how do I use `defineProperty`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you use `defineProperty` to do it. In my example I'm logging each time `window.$` is assigned, along with a call stack. Of course instead of logging you can trigger a `debugger;` or do something else.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "$",
{
  set: function(val) {
    console.log("$ was set to '",val,"' at ",Error().stack);
    this.$internal=val;
  },
  get: function() { return this.$internal; }
});
```